# @MockBean results in NullPointerException for @SpringBatchTest in Junit 5

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-batch, junit5

I am trying to use the @MockBean annotation in my Spring Batch Test, but I am unable to get it to work.  I have simplified my test to it's most basic form for this post.  Essentially, @Autowired works (so I know the class is being picked up by Spring), but when I replace it with the @MockBean annotation, the bean is not mocked (it's null). Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

This works fine.

```
@SpringBatchTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestAppConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EmailQueueBatchConfigTestFail {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserEmailSender appUserEmailSender;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        if (appUserEmailSender == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the mocked object here is null

```
@SpringBatchTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestAppConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EmailQueueBatchConfigTestFail {

    @MockBean
    private AppUserEmailSender appUserEmailSender;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        if (appUserEmailSender == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're talking about `appUserEmailSender`?  What do you expect it to be set to?  Have you declared a mock somewhere?  If so, show us.  If not...well there's your answer. `@MockBean` by itself isn't going to do anything.  You have to have defined a mock of `AppUserEmailSender` for it to insert into your class.

Comment: how do I define the mock?  I am used to defining mocks like: `appUserEmailSender = mock(AppUserEmailSender.class);`  Is that what I should do?  I thought that would overwrite the @MockBean object?

Comment: On my original test, the `if (appUserEmailSender == null)` was actually: `when(appUserEmailSender.send(any())).thenReturn(new EmailQueue());`  But that of course gave a NPE

Comment: ...sorry...I realized that my comments are probably just confusing things.  apologies.

Comment: Thanks for sending the link - that was the exact tutorial I used to create the test class ;-)  You can see from the example that I am, in fact, using @MockBean inside my annotated test class.  Oddly, when I remove any method reference to `appUserEmailSender` in my test class (thus avoiding the NPE and allowing the test to run), the `appUserEmailSender` service is mocked inside other `@Autowired` objects.  So this tells me that the @MockBean annotation is working.  It's just not allowing me to define the mock's behavior in the test class (e.g. 'when().then()') since it's null.

Comment: Do you think one of my test annotations could be messing with something?

Comment: I think I solved my problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7177  When I removed the `@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})` annotation, it works as intended.

Comment: Glad you got it!  Gave your answer a thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you use the annotations `@MockBean` and `@TestExecutionListeners` in the same test class, the `MockitoTestExecutionListener` may not be called.  To remedy this, you need to add `TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS` to the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation.

So a corrected version would look like...

```
@SpringBatchTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestAppConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(
        listeners = {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class},
        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@TestPropertySource(properties = "app.scheduling.enable=false") // disable @Scheduled annotation
public class SimpleTest {

    @MockBean
    private AppUserEmailSender appUserEmailSender;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(appUserEmailSender.send(any())).thenReturn(new EmailQueue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the listeners you registered are registered by default, you should be able to completely omit the `@TestExecutionListeners` declaration.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.